# How Android Draws Views

Tags: android, android-layout, tree

In [How Android Draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html):

"Because the tree is traversed in-order, this means that parents will be drawn before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order they appear in the tree."

Does the author actually mean "pre-order", instead of "in-order"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have any definition for your concepts of "pre-order" and "in-order". I guess the author just refers to the fact that there is an order, and views are not refreshed in an absolute chaotic way. :)

Comment: I think he's referring to tree traversal ordering. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's more like "depth-first order" for measuring the children and "pre-order" for the actual drawing.
The parent will be drawn first and the children stacked on top of the parent.

Comment: The measuring phase would also be a pre-order traversal, why the difference?

Comment: You could have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in your parent so the children have to get measured in order to know the size of the content

Comment: pre-order is a form of depth first search.

Comment: what about the right childs? if measuring is done in-order we get the size of all the children in the left but what about the children in the right? how will it get the size of the left childrens.

before parent is drawn all the child should be measured then parent should be drawn. I guess the measuring should be post order and actual drawing should be pre-order

Answer (score 5):

**That is a bug in the documentation**. It should be pre-order traversal where the parent draws before children.

Most UI toolkit libraries (including android) do this:

- render the view hierarchy top down in pre-order - first draw self,
  then children
- Measure (size calculation) happens bottom up in post-order - first
  measure children, then measure self
- Layout (positioning) happens top down in pre-order - first my parent
  positions me, then i position my children